# undefined method `delete' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) capybara, selenium-webdriver and firefox in arch linux

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara, archlinux

I am writing because I am having troubles running a test using cucumber and capybara. I am using capybara framework with selenium-driver. This is my env.rb

```
require 'capybara/cucumber'

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
```

This is my steps.rb file

```
Given (/^I am on Youtube$/) do 
  visit "http://www.youtube.com"
end

When (/^I fill in "([^"]*)" with "([^"]*)"$/) do |field, value|
  fill_in(field, :with => value)
end

When (/^I press "([^"]*)"$/) do |button|
  click_button(button)
end

Then (/^I should see "([^"]*)"$/) do |text|
  page.should have_content(text)
end
```

And this the output that i obtain. I tried to execute the same file with cucumber in a Mac system and it works. I am using Arch Linux (antergos) with kernel version 4.10.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT

```
Feature: YouTube has a search function.

  Scenario: Search for a term                                    # features/youtube_search.feature:3
    Given I am on Youtube                                        # features/step_definitions/youtube_search_steps.rb:1
      undefined method `delete' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
      ./features/step_definitions/youtube_search_steps.rb:2:in `/^I am on Youtube$/'
      features/youtube_search.feature:4:in `Given I am on Youtube'
    When I fill in "search_query" with "text adventure"          # features/step_definitions/youtube_search_steps.rb:5
    And I press "search-btn"                                     # features/step_definitions/youtube_search_steps.rb:9
    Then I should see "GET LAMP: The Text Adventure Documentary" # features/step_definitions/youtube_search_steps.rb:13

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/youtube_search.feature:3 # Scenario: Search for a term

1 scenario (1 failed)
4 steps (1 failed, 3 skipped)
0m1.898s
```

**NOTE:** When I run the cucumber command, a new firefox window is opened, but I see the error mentioned in the terminal and test not continue.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Do you have anything more in your output that shows the actual code line the error occurred on, instead of just the step line?

Comment: No, sorry, nothing. I made work it using chrome, but in firefox is not working... I imagine it is a problem with the latest versions of the browser, although downgrading the application did not work either...

Comment: Try updating geckodriver - also you can try running cucumber with the --backtrace option and see if it gives any deeper info about where the error actually occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem. It happens when the selenium-webdriver and Firefox versions don't match. As Firefox gets updated fairly often you will get this error from time to time. If you update your selenium-web it should fix the problem. It did for me.